# Can I add/merge 2 OpenIds on the same account?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I thought I read a blog post but when I tried it on Startups.com it just keeps logging me out as one user and back in as the other.

Is this allowed? And is it something StackExchange sites can turn on/off?

Comment: Please ask this on http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's a question about SO. I just used Startups as an example.

Comment: When you go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/142298/john, do you see an "add openid" link? Or is that what you already tried?

Comment: If you have two SO accounts (with different OpenIds), you have to send a mail to the SO teams to have them merged. For the other sites, you'll have to ask on http://meta.stackexchange.com/ whether it's possible for StackExchange sites to do this at all, and contact the specific site owner as to how it would be done.

Comment: Oh I see. I can add an OpenID to a non-OpenID account and they'll get merged, but I can't automatically merge 2 accounts both having OpenIDs already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you registered the two openids seperately, you'll need to contact team@stackoverflow to have them merged, unless this is a stackexchange site.  There you will need to find out who the site administrators are and ask them to merge the accounts.

I don't believe there's a way for you to easily add an openid to an account if the id you are trying to add already exists in the system with another account.  There may be a way if you disassociate the ID with the existing account and then re-add it, but I don't know whether the system will accept that attempt.